# MultipleRow Selection and texboxs in Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

I have this code that works when I select a single Row and enters them correctly where they go, now the issue is that I have to select 1x1, there is a way to choose the first row and then action is repeated for the other 5 below it In the order they are? As you can see, each one has different textboxes, or if there is a guide or YouTube video where I could gather information on how to do it or whether or not I will always have to do 1x1

```
  int rowCount = dataGridView2.RowCount; // Obtener el número total de filas en el DataGridView

  if (rowCount >= 6)
  {
      int selectedRowIndex = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex; // Obtener la fila actualmente seleccionada

      if (selectedRowIndex >= 0 && selectedRowIndex < 6)
      {
          if (selectedRowIndex == 0)
          {
              txtDniEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2Esposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtNombreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
              txtPaisEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 1)
          {
              txtDniEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2Esposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtNombreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
              txtPaisEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 2)
          {
              txtDniMadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoMadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2MadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtNombreMadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
              
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 3)
          {
              txtDniPadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoPadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2PadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtNombreMadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 4)
          {
              txtDniPadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoPadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2PadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtNombrePadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 5)
          {
              txtDniMadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              textBox3.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              textBox4.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtMadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
          }

          // Realiza aquí las operaciones que necesites con los datos asignados a los TextBox
      }
      else
      {
          
      }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOkLX.png) i Expect when i do 1 click in Cargar Datos Casamiento to get all the info and not going 1x1

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want. But can't you loop over your rows? To fill the controls maybe they could be stored in a dictionary where key is selectedRowIndex or something like that?

Comment: i want when i select row 1 ,the first one , the other five get selected too for the inputs for the textboxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can be significantly simplified for perception as follows:

```
if (selectedRowIndex >= 0 && selectedRowIndex < 6)
{
    var name1 = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    var name2 = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    var name3 = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    var name4 = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    var name5 = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();

    if (selectedRowIndex == 0)
    {
        txtDniEsposo.Text = name1;
        txtApellido2Esposo.Text = name2;
        txtApellidoEsposo.Text = name3;
        txtNombreEsposo.Text = name4;
        txtPaisEsposo.Text = name5;
    }
    else if (selectedRowIndex == 1)
    {
        txtDniEsposa.Text = name1;
        txtApellido2Esposa.Text = name2;
        txtApellidoEsposa.Text = name3;
        txtNombreEsposa.Text = name4;
        txtPaisEsposa.Text = name5;
    }
    ...
```

Of course, instead of `name1`, `name2`, give the variables descriptive names.

You can shorten the code even more:

```
var cells = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells;

var name1 = cells[4].Value.ToString();
var name2 = cells[2].Value.ToString();
var name3 = cells[1].Value.ToString();
var name4 = cells[0].Value.ToString();
var name5 = cells[8].Value.ToString();
```